# Склонение наименования пос.Ямбург

Tags: склонение

Добрый день! Пожалуйста, подскажите правильный вариант: В п.Ямбург или в п.Ямбурге?

Comment: "[Склонение географических названий в русском языке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)" - Википедия.

Answer (score 3):

Чем менее известен населенный пункт, тем с большим основанием необходимо сохранять точность его названия.

Поэтому мы говорим: в городе Ямбурге, в поселке Ямбурге и Ямбург, на станции Ямбург.

Comment: _Vera:
"Чем менее известен населенный пункт, тем с большим основанием необходимо сохранять точность его названия.

Поэтому мы говорим... на станции Ямбург."_ === Гм... Vera, неужели Вы считаете, что когда эта станция станет очень-очень известной, говорить станут "на станции Ямбурге"???

Comment: slava, для СТАНЦИИ Ямбург вряд ли что изменится, а вот ПОСЕЛОК Ямбург вполне может  превратиться в город,  который будет ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО СКЛОНЯТЬСЯ, если столица автоматически туда переедет и Ямбург станет "элегантнейшим центром Европы, а скоро и всего мира".

Comment: _Vera: "для СТАНЦИИ Ямбург вряд ли что изменится"._ === Угу. Потому я и не понял, зачем Вы написали: "Чем менее известен населенный пункт, тем с большим основанием необходимо сохранять точность его названия. **Поэтому** мы говорим... на станции Ямбург."

Comment: Я хотела сказать, что для малоизвестных топонимов требуется бОльшая точность наименования, поэтому они не склоняются. (Также  на склоняемость влияет стиль речи: официальный, профессиональный или разговорный). Поэтому мы говорим "на станции Ямбург".

Answer (score 2):

По общему правилу название должно склоняться: *в поселке Ямбурге*.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

**§197. Приложения – географические названия**

А мне почему-то хочется написать: *в поселке Ямбург*. Но: *в городе Ямбурге*.

Comment: Niemand: "А мне почему-то хочется написать: _в поселке Ямбург_". === И мне тоже!

Comment: Может, это из-за того, что ну не может поселок оканчиваться на -бург! И вот, чтобы это подчеркнуть, мы и идем на небольшое нарушение. ))

Comment: Скорее, от ощущения бесполезности этого правила, расхождения его во многом с языковой практикой - в тщетном стремлении обнимать необъятное и утверждать единомыслие :) "В Ямбурге, но "в посёлке Ямбург (Комарово, г. Вышний Волочёк)"

Answer (score 1):

Винительный падеж -  Ямбург. В Ямгурге - предложный падеж.

Answer (score 0):

> Пожалуйста, подскажите правильный вариант: В п. Ямбург или в п.
>   Ямбурге?

**Правильны оба варианта, но предпочтительный...**

=========

В Гугл-книгах:

["в поселке Ямбург"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%22&tbm=bks) -- Результатов: 8

["в поселке Ямбурге"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%22&tbm=bks) -- Результатов: примерно 0

["в п Ямбург"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%22&tbm=bks) -- Результатов: 4

["в п Ямбурге"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%20%D0%AF%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%22&tbm=bks) -- Результатов: примерно 0

=========

Выводы сделайте сами.